# not to validate a page on onclick

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in my application.

I'm validation a page on a Click of Save button.But validation applies for all available buttons in the page.Here is my code:

**Default.aspx**

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtName" class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-right">
                        Asset Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ToolTip="Name" TextMode="MultiLine"
                            Width="300px" Style="resize: none;" data-val-required=" Name is required."
                            data-val="true"> </asp:TextBox>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-warning red" data-valmsg-for="txtName"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtLocation" class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-right">
                        Location</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" ToolTip="Location" data-val-required=" Location is required."
                            Width="300px" data-val="true"> </asp:TextBox>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-warning red" data-valmsg-for="txtLocation"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div> 
</div>
</div>

 <div class="pull-right">
  <button id="btnSave" title="Save" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                onclick="Save();" runat="server">
                Save
            </button>
  <button id="btnCancel" title="Save & Next" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                onclick="Cancel();" runat="server">
                Cancel
            </button>
        </div>
</div>

 <asp:Button ID="btnCancelPage" runat="server" OnClick="btnCancelPage_Click"
        Style="display: none" />

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function Cancel(){
$("#btnCancelPage").Click();
}
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSave,#btnCancel').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
  });
        });
</script>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
  protected void btnCancelPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Context.Items.Add("ID", "10");

        string targetPath ="~/SamplePage.aspx";

        Server.Transfer(targetPath);
    }
```

when i click on the cancel button, Page validation is occurring.
I dont want to validate the page while Cancel button is clicked.

Please help me out.

Comment: `<asp:Button CauseValidation="false" ID="btnCancel" />`

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net page validators?

Comment: im validating using these js -> jquery.validate.js & jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Answer (score 0):

Use linkbutton to ignore your validation

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-info" runat="server" ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" PostBackUrl="~/default.aspx"></asp:LinkButton>
```

you may also add an OnClick() event in linkbutton.. i just used the PostBackUrl as a sample on redirecting to other page.

I hope this will help you

Comment: thank u. But i need to pass a query string value while navigating to the other page

Comment: you may remove the postbackUrl and replace with OnClick="" same as your example like this <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancelPage" runat="server" OnClick="btnCancelPage_Click"
        Style="display: none" />